# Matlab reading 24-bit ascii-hex file into a 32-bit signed

Tags: matlab, type-conversion

I'd like to plot every 9th element from an ascii file containg a single column of 24-bit signed hex values

```
ex.
813457
123456
241566
etc..
```

The problem is, I can't get Matlab to treat values 800000-FFFFFF as negative, presumably because it's not sign extending it into 32-bits.

I thought of breaking it up into strings, then converting, but sscanf requires the '0x' to convert signed %i hex values so I'm forced to use unsigned:

```
 C = textscan(fp, '%s')        %generates 16380x1 cell  (instead of normal array?!)
 sscanf (C{1,1}{1,1}, '%x')    %convert first ascii hex element from cell to unsigned hex
```

Interestingly, as a test, just doing hex2dec('FFC00000') results in a postive number, how can I force all the ascii lines in the file to be imported as an array of signed 24 or 32bit data?

Comment: Just to make sure: what would the appropriate result of `FFC00000` be?

Comment: It should be -4194304... as a simple test, using windows' programming calculator you can enter negative decimal values and then switch to Hex to see it's corresponding 2's compliment hex number.

Answer (score 0):

To do the conversion you need, you can follow these steps:

1. Convert from hex string to a positive integer of `double` type, using `herx2dec`, as you've already done.
2. Convert that value to `uint32` type.
3. Interpret that `uint32` value as an `int32` (convert data type without changing underlying data), using [`typecast`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html).

Example:

```
>> typecast(uint32(hex2dec('FFC00000')),'int32')
ans =
    -4194304
```

Comment: Thanks, except the data isn't already sign extended (i.e. the file has the data in 24-bit format C00000 not 32-bit FFC00000), so using hex2dec on C00000 leads to a positive number after typecasting to int32.

Comment: @BenNguyen, the method will work. You have to first extend your string with two trailing zeros (to get full 32 bits hex representation), do the conversion, then divide by 'FF' or 256 since you'll be in decimal at that point. so:  `padding = '00' ; typecast( uint32( hex2dec(['C00000' padding])) , 'int32' ) / 256` will produce `-4194304`. And the same operation with `7F0000` for example, will result in `8323072`.